# unix command to scan xml file for double quotes within double quotes

Tags: xml, unix

Please help with command to find the double quotes within double quotes in a xml file.

```
 eg: instead of <wc:Address_Data>"mg road, bungalow 48"
 we getting <wc:Address_Data>"mg road, "bungalow" 48"
```

Comment: Do you only want to _find_ the latter, or replace the latter with the former?

Comment: I want to find the latter. Don't want to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd approach the problem by looking for two additional quotes before the next tag:

```
grep '>"[^<]*"[^<]*"'
```

Answer (score 0):

You and I can tell that there are (apparently) nested double quotes in

*"mg road, "bungalow" 48"*

and that the quotes are not nested in:

*"Boo", he said, and then "Bother".*

But how is the computer supposed to tell the difference?